# Jquery + PHP - AJAX onclick favorite/unfavorite

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So far I have tried using a simple php GET request as well as a POST request, nothing seems to work.

Here is the Javascript code I have thus far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

favGame();

// Favorite Link //
function favGame() {

    $("a.arfavorite").click(function() {
        $.get("favorites.php", {gid: gid, ar: ar}, function() {
            alert("it all worked");
        });
        return false;
    });
} });
```

Here is the PHP code I have thus far:

```
 if (!isset($favorites[$game['id']])) {
    echo "Add To My Favorites";
} else {
    echo "Remove From My Favorites";
}
```

Comment: Well `gid` and `ar` are not defined in the code you have given. I am not sure how gid maps to $game id and you should be using a POST request.

Comment: ok sir I will try change

Comment: 1st step to check Whether or not ajax is working is : Hit it thru URL like -> **favorites.php?gid=123&ar=123** . If it fails your PHP code is Wrong.

Comment: Can you please write function favGame() after document ready brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try implementing like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    favGame();

    // Favorite Link //
    function favGame() {
var gid=123;//set values to send
var ar=23;
        $("a.arfavorite").click(function() {
            $.post("submit.php", {gid: gid, ar: ar}, function() {
                alert("it all worked");
            });
            return false;
        });
    } });
</script>

<a class="arfavorite">click</a>
```

your php will be:

```
<?php 
print_r($_POST);// only to check if post variables are coming

if (!isset($_POST['gid'])) {
    echo "Add To My Favorites";
} else {
    echo "Remove From My Favorites";
}
?>
```

in console response you will see this:

```
Array
(
    [gid] => 123
    [ar] => 23
)
Remove From My Favorites
```